# importing global variable in python from different module

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I have main.py

```
globvar = 0

def set_globvar_to_one():
    global globvar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    globvar = 1
```

and cs.py

```
from main import globvar
from main import set_globvar_to_one

def print_globvar():
    print(globvar)     # No need for global declaration to read value of globvar

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()
```

when i run cs.py output of above code is 0. where as i was expecting output is 1 as from cs.py i modified the global variable present in main.py .I imported globvar in cs.py ?

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the output of the following code:

```py
globvar = 0

def set_glob_var():
    global globvar

    print "In set_glob_var 1: ", id(globvar)
    globvar = 1
    print "In set_glob_var 2: ", id(globvar)
```

and then:

```py
from main import globvar
from main import set_glob_var

print "Outside of main 1", id(globvar)
globvar = 1
print "Outside of main 2", id(globvar)
```

It turn out that it will print something like:

```
Outside of main 1: <id globvar 1>
In set_glob_var 1: <id globvar 1>
In set_glob_var 2: <id globvar 2>
Outside of main 2: <id globvar 1>
```

Notice that all the ids of globvar will be the same, except for that in line 3. So, when you try to change the value of the variable, it will reset the id to a different address, within the module being imported, since the variable is already global an is stored in the cache.

You can explore this further by calling set_glob_var multiple times. The results will be interesting!